Class inherits two override-equivalent methods
Consider this rule from the Java Language Specification 21th edition:

It is a compile-time error if a class C inherits a default method whose signature is override-equivalent with another method inherited by C, unless there exists an abstract method declared in a superclass of C and inherited by C that is override-equivalent with the two methods.

You can find the definition of "override-equivalent" here.
Now, consider the following code:
interface I {
    default void m(List l) {
        System.out.println("I");
    }
}

class A {
    public void m(List<String> l) {
        System.out.println("A");
    }
}

public class B extends A implements I {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        I x = new B();
        List list = null;
        x.m(list); // invokes impl in A
    }
}

Class B inherits the default method m(List) from interface I and also inherits the method m(List<String>) from its superclass A. These two methods are override-equivalent because the signature of m in interface I is a subsignature of the signature of m as defined in class A.
According to the rule, this code should not compile, since there is no abstract method in the inheritance chain that is override-equivalent to both methods. However, the code does compile.
Why does it compile? If this program is not a counterexample to the rule, what mistake did I make in my reasoning?
UPDATE: Some comments and answers suggest that C does not inherit I.m, and instead it is overridden by A.m, which is not true according to the rules in the JLS. In the section Inheritance, Overriding, and Hiding, part two, which specifically deals with default and abstract method inheritance, lists five conditions for a default or abstract method m to be inherited by a class C. The first three are easy to verify. The third condition states that there should be no concrete method m' inherited by C such that the signature of m' is a subsignature of m. The only candidate method m' in my example is A.m. Is the signature of A.m a subsignature of I.m? No, according to the definition of the subsignature relation. So this condition is also satisfied. For the last condition, I is not a superinterface of A, so it is satisfied. Thus, B does inherit I.m, which also implies that A.m does not override I.m in B, according to the rules of overriding an interface method in the section Overriding (by Instance Methods), which states that for an interface method m to be overridden in a class C, C must not inherit m. Therefore, B in the example above inherits both methods. The two methods are override-equivalent according to the definition, hence the conditions for the JLS rule mentioned at the top of this question which is mentioned in the section Inheriting Methods with Override-Equivalent Signatures are all satisfied, which should result in a compiler error.
An easy way to verify that A.m does not override I.m is by simply making m in interface I abstract, and you will observe that the code no longer compiles.
PS: This question is different from the question (Super class method and Interface default method conflict resolution, which is about WHY a method inherited from a super class can override another default method declared in a super interface, while the current question deals with case where the code SHOULD NOT COMPILE according to a JLS rule, but yet it compiles.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Eclipse’s compiler does reject this code but produces the confusing error message: Duplicate methods named m with the parameters (List<String>) and (List<String>) are defined by the type A

Based on the rule, the code should not compile. A similar bug (JDK-8284566) has been opened in the JDK bug system.

The rule you mentioned typically applies when there is no concrete method from a super-class, and multiple default methods from interfaces create ambiguity. However, in this case, A's concrete method resolves that ambiguity before it even becomes an issue, which is why the compile-time error doesn't apply here.
Class A provides a concrete implementation of the m() method. So, whenever m() gets called on any instance of A (or its subclass B), it's A's implementation that gets executed. Even though B implements the interface I, it's A that defines the method, so there's no need for B to rely on the interface.
interface I<E> {
    default void m(List<E> l) {}
}

class A {
    public void m(List<String> l) { System.out.println(l);  }
}

class B extends A implements I<String> {}

Three ways to look at method invocation
1. Using I<String> with class B
Even though B implements I<String>, when you call m(List<String> l) on an instance of B, it will use A's version of the method, not the default one from I<String>. The reason is that A already provides a concrete implementation, which takes precedence over the default interface method.
I<String> foo = new B();
foo.m(List.of("X", "Y", "Z"));

2. Direct invocation on class A
When you call m(List<String> l) directly on an instance of A, it's simply A's concrete method that runs. There's no interface involved here, so it's a straightforward call to A's method.
A foo = new A();
foo.m(List.of("X", "Y", "Z"));

3. Inheritance in class B
Since B extends A, when you call m() on an instance of B, it will still use the method inherited from A. The implementation from A is inherited, so no need to look at the interface's default method.
B foo = new B();
foo.m(List.of("X", "Y", "Z"));

Making A an abstract class
If A is abstract and defines m() as an abstract method, B must provide its own implementation of m(List<String> l). In this case, the interface's default method gets ignored because A defines the method's signature.
interface I<E> {
    default void m(List<E> l) { System.out.println("Unimplemented..."); }
}

abstract class A {
    public abstract void m(List<String> l); // Declared abstract (shadows the default)
}

class B extends A implements I<String> {
    // Class 'B' must either be declared abstract or implement
    // abstract method 'm(List<String>)' in 'A'
    @Override
    public void m(List<String> l) {
        System.out.println(l);
    }
}

class C implements I<Integer> {}

A foo = new A(); // Error: A is abstract and cannot be instantiated

C foo = new C();
foo.m(List.of(1, 2, 3)); // prints "Unimplemented"


Class A's implementation: Since A provides a concrete version of m(List<String> l), it's always the method that gets called, even when you work with B. The default method in the interface isn't used because A takes over with its implementation.

Abstract class scenario: If A is abstract and doesn't provide an implementation for m(), then B has to step in and provide its own. In this case, the interface's default method still gets ignored because A has claimed the method signature, even if it's abstract.

Default method in C: In C, which implements I<Integer>, the default method from I is used since C doesn't have its own implementation for m(List<Integer> l) and no superclass has overridden it.


Summary
The code snippets above shows how Java resolves method calls when both an interface and a super-class are involved.
Concrete class methods always override interface default methods, and when abstract classes are in play, sub-classes need to implement the abstract methods even if the interface provides a default one.

I understand why the example you gave compiles, but it is not the same as the example I provided in the question. Take my example and remove the default modifier from m in interface I, and you will see that the method m as declared in B does not override m in interface I. crafted this example specifically for this not to happen.

@MohamedNasser what about class C implements I<Integer> {}? Whether or not B implements I does not matter, since it extends A; and A provides the same method signature (after type erasure). Java does its best to reconcile between the interface and the concrete class.

Is this answer in agreement with user85421 in the comments and also with Holger in the linked thread?

@jaco0646 The first two paragraphs are in agreement with what user85421 said. The answer is discussing a normal case that is the main of the question linked in your comment.
